# I'm triying install DJonDB in ubuntu 12.10, and show me "djon: no se encontro la orden"..please help me

Tags: database, installation, ubuntu-12.10

I'm trying to install `DJonDB` on **Ubuntu 12.10**. I'm following the directions in this blog post:

- http://crosstantine.blogspot.com/2013/01/preparacion-para-taller-de-nosql-con.html

.. but I'm getting the following error:

```
% djondb -n
djon: no se encontro la orden
```

Answer (score 0):

it's because you should be using "djondbd" instead of just "djondb", the blog is fixed now.